# Korn shell and Bash substitute variable with space over SSH

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, ksh, ibm-hmc

I have been trying to collect the LPAR id details in by executing a remote command from AIX server (Korn Shell) to IBM HMC (restricted Bash Shell) over SSH.

Im having trouble in substituting the lpar names with spaces over SSH.

Below is the total servers in the frame.  Could you please help me with the solution on substituting the variable LPAR on SSH for HMC

```
vio1001
vio1002
lpar4556 PROD DBX02
```

Script Tried:

```
oldIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
set -o noglob
for lpar in $(ssh -nq hscroot@ibmhmc101 "lssyscfg -r lpar -m frame220-aix-p750 -F name,lpar_env" | cut -d, -f 1 | sort)
do
   echo "$lpar"
   for state in $(ssh -nq hscroot@ibmhmc101 "oldIFS=$IFS; IFS=$'\n';set -o noglob;lssyscfg -m frame220-aix-p750 -r lpar -F name:state --filter lpar_names="${lpar}" << "EOF"
EOF" | cut -d: -f2)
   do
      echo $state
   done
done

Error: 
vio1001
vio1002
lpar4556 PROD DBX02
/bin/bash: line 1: vio1001: command not found
/bin/bash: line 2: vio1002: command not found

Ru

i
g
```

Comment: There is a problem in substituting the variable with lpar names in spaces ( lpar4556 PROD DBX02)

Comment: what do you intend with `<< "EOF"` in inner `for` ?

Comment: 1) what is the output of `lssyscfg -m frame220-aix-p750 -r lpar -F name:state --filter lpar_names=vio1001` ?

Comment: Last I knew, the HMC shell had a shell that could nest `for` loops; any reason you don't loop inside the HMC shell?

Comment: Hi @JeffSchaller i would like to collect the LPAR details and frame and related LPAR id details for all servers on different HMC's..

Comment: @Archemar I can login to the HMC and get the details. But couldn't try to get on SSH for variables having spaces. for vio1001 im able to execute the filter command using SSH output - vio1001:Running

Comment: It seems to me that your first `for lpar in $(sssh ...` loop is asking lssyscfg  for two comma-delimited items (name,lpar_env), but then you're using `cut` to extract only the first item. Perhaps simplify your code to return only what you need? Ditto the second loop where you're asking for "name:state" and then cutting for field 2.

Comment: Why can you *not* run: `ssh -nq hscroot@ibmhmc101 lssyscfg -m frame220-aix-p750 -r lpar -F name:state` ?

Comment: @JeffSchaller I can run like the command you have.. But im unable to use the flag --filter as it doesnt filter by LPAR name

Comment: Why do you need to filter on the LPAR name? You're looping through all of the LPARs anyway...?

Comment: @JeffSchaller the lssyscfg by frame name lists all the LPAR's in the frame. So to get the details for specific LPAR, Would need to use the --filter flag.  Also i have to search on how to loop by lpar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried the below workaround using while read line. This fixed my issue.

```
ssh hscroot@$hmc "lssyscfg -r lpar -m $frame -F name,lpar_env" | cut -d, -f1 | sort | while read line
do
lpar=`echo ${line} | cut -d= -f2`
echo "$lpar"
for lpar_id in $(ssh -nq hscroot@$hmc "lssyscfg -r lpar -m $frame -F name:lpar_env:lpar_id --filter lpar_names="${lpar}" " | cut -d: -f3 | sort)
do
echo "$lpar_id"
done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to protect **lpar** so i will add **\** before each double-quote

This is a example , that test both :

```
for lpar in "1"  "2 3" "2;3" "abc" "abc def" "abc;def"   ; 
do 
     echo "#${lpar}#" ;
     ssh XXXX@EXAMPLE.COM  "printf 'arg1:%s arg2:%s\n'  --filter  par_names=\"${lpar}\"  " ;
     ssh XXXX@EXAMPLE.COM  "printf 'arg1:%s arg2:%s\n'  --filter  par_names="${lpar}"  " ;
done
```

Comment: Still getting same error. Looks like it is not picking the LPAR name with spaces.